# Compiling alarm script using cx_Freeze and simpleaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

### Context

1. I downgraded my python to 3.4.4
2. so I could use the cx_Freeze module
3. since I want my script in exe format
4. so that I can send it to a friend of mine who doesn't have python.

I have figured out how it works on a single script with no modules imported. This is a problem since I wrote a script that functions like an alarm clock earlier, but to play the selected wav file (input being the filename) I needed a third party module called simpleaudio.

### Question

How can I make the exe run the script properly?

### Code

alarm.py:

```
import simpleaudio
import subprocess
import datetime

print("Set a wav audio file")
wav = input()
wav = str(wav)
print("Set alarm time")
print("hour.minute")
alarmtime = input()
alarmtime = str(alarmtime)

while alarmtime != "%02d.%02d" % (datetime.datetime.now().time().hour, datetime.datetime.now().time().minute):
    print("%02d.%02d.%02d" % (datetime.datetime.now().time().hour, datetime.datetime.now().time().minute, datetime.datetime.now().time().second))

print("Playing",wav)
wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(wav)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

setup.py:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import simpleaudio
import subprocess
import datetime

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("alarm.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "alarm",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["simpleaudio","subprocess","datetime"], "include_files":["rasputin.wav"]}},
    executables = executables
    )
```